# "ListView", but "summary of new entries" (not "new entry summary")?

Tags: prepositions

I had a discussion with my programmer colleague about the word order and prepositions in English. The discussion started when he named one website "new entry summary". That sounded wrong to me and I suggested "summary of new entries". I broke it down by parts of speech, showing that it's unnatural to put together two nouns like that. His counterargument was that many programming components are named this way, for example "ListView". I told him that I have a feeling that it's something different, but couldn't justify why preposition seems out of place here, but necessary in "new entry summary". Am I wrong? If not, what's the difference and how could I try to explain it?

Comment: Names, titles, headings, websites and the like are generally constructed with brevity and clarity in mind, rather than correct grammar. In short, you can call them anything you like.

Comment: It is not unnatural to make a phrase of two nouns.  It's actually very common: apple pie, dog walker, rain cloud and on and on and on.  You can search this site, or elsewhere on the internet for "attributive noun" to learn more about it.